# memory consumption and lifetime of temporaries

Tags: python

I've a python code where the memory consumption steadily grows with time. While there are several objects which can legitimately grow quite large, I'm trying to understand whether the memory footprint I'm observing is due to these objects, or is it just me littering the memory with temporaries which don't get properly disposed of --- Being a recent convert from a world of manual memory management, I guess I just don't exactly understand some very basic aspects of how the python runtime deals with temporary objects.

Consider a code with roughly this general structure (am omitting irrelevant details):

```
def tweak_list(lst):
    new_lst = copy.deepcopy(lst)
    if numpy.random.rand() > 0.5:
        new_lst[0] += 1  # in real code, the operation is a little more sensible :-)
        return new_lst
    else:
        return lst


lst = [1, 2, 3]
cache = {}

# main loop
for step in xrange(some_large_number):

    lst = tweak_list(lst)    # <<-----(1)

    # do something with lst here, cut out for clarity

    cache[tuple(lst)] = 42   # <<-----(2)

    if step%chunk_size == 0:
        # dump the cache dict to a DB, free the memory (?)
        cache = {}           # <<-----(3)
```

Questions:

1. What is the lifetime of a `new_list` created in a `tweak_list`? Will it be destroyed on exit, or will it be garbage collected (at which point?). Will repeated calls to `tweak_list` generate a gazillion of small lists lingering around for a long time?
2. Is there a temporary creation when converting a `list` to a `tuple` to be used as a `dict` key?
3. Will setting a `dict` to an empty one release the memory?
4. Or, am I approaching the issue at hand from a completely wrong perspective?

Comment: When you run the code you've shown here, do you still see the memory increase over time?

Comment: Q: why are you using ``deepcopy()``? Does your list contain more complex objects then numbers? If no, why not use a shallow copy or just ``list()``. If yes, then that's most likely the reason for the leak as they will get copied and then stored in cache as keys.

Comment: @lqc: in the (admittedly stupid) example here, the `tweak_list` modifies its argument in roughly 50% of calls; in other 50% it needs to leave the list intact. Sure, I could just operate on a view, `lst[:]`, but would that be really different?

Comment: @interjay: No, there isn't. My question was more about what's going under the python's hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `new_lst` is cleaned up when the function exists when not returned. It's reference count drops to 0, and it can be garbage collected. On current cpython implementations that happens immediately.

   If it *is* returned, the value referenced by `new_lst` replaces `lst`; the list referred to by `lst` sees it's reference count drop by 1, but the value originally referred to by `new_lst` is still being referred to by another variable.
2. The `tuple()` key is a value stored in the `dict`, so that's not a temporary. No extra objects are created other than that tuple.
3. Replacing the old `cache` dict with a new one will reduce the reference count by one. If `cache` was the only reference to the dict it'll be garbage collected. This then causes the reference count for all contained tuple keys to drop by one. If nothing else references to those those will be garbage collected.
4. Note that when Python frees memory, that does not necessarily mean the operating system reclaims it immediately. Most operating systems will only reclaim the memory when it is needed for something else, instead presuming the program might need some or all of that memory again soon.

Comment: @lqc: clarified; it is not always returned.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) as a way of profiling memory usage. I think [PySizer](http://pysizer.8325.org/) is also used in some instances for this but I am not familiar with it. [ObjGraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) is also a strong tool to take a lok at.